# How do I zoom into text with JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, zoom, system-preferences

I would like to zoom in on text for presentations or when I need to focus on one function within the code.

How can I do this on a Mac OS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATED 13JUN22:**

It seems that a newer version of IDEA causes the steps listed here to not find **Zoom** keyword.

Instead, search for `font size` and make sure you are in the `Editor > General` section. Click the checkbox and you're off an running again.

[image]

---

I found that you can enable this feature within IntelliJ by opening `Preferences`(`⌘,`) > click in the search and then enter the word `zoom`. Check the box for `Change font size (Zoom) with Command+Mouse Wheel`.

[image: image of zoom search]

Now you can hold down the Command and scroll your mouse wheel to zoom in and zoom out.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I restore to the default size?

Comment: Looks like a new question is in order. 

Answer (score 2):

You can keymap the usual Cmd +/-/0 in the IntelliJ (or Android Studio) keymap settings by searching for font size in the keymap. Go ahead and set it as shown in the screenshot, and IntelliJ will ask you whether you want to remove it from other assignments.

This works well and it *should* be the default!
[image: Screenshot of font size settings from IntelliJ]

Answer (score 0):

2023

Ubuntu

File >Settings > General (CTRL+ALT+S (small s will not work )) > Mouse Control > Change font size with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel in: All editors